# I need to take amount value from below phase using regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace, regex-look-ahead

1. some text here
2. some text here
3. Amount  :  #4,227,361,94#
4. some text here
5. some text here
6. Amount  :  #227,361,94#

Answer (score 1):

Below regex pattern will return entire String

```
[0-9]+\:\s[a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

If you want only numbers use below pattern

```
^[0-9]+
or
[0-9]+
or
^[0-9]+$
```